# Javascript reduce accumulator unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

The code below is supposed to count the # of 4 in the numbers array.
Why does the one with the acc++ not give the expected behavior?

```
>>>   numbers
(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4]
>>>   numbers.filter(n => n === 4).reduce( (acc, num) => acc = acc + 1, 0)
3
>>>   numbers.filter(n => n === 4).reduce( (acc, num) => acc++, 0)
0
```

Comment: because of the order of `++` on the left side it adds in advance and retuns the new value. on the right side, it returns the value first and increment later.

Comment: You want `(acc) => acc + 1` as the callback. But really you should use just `.length` instead of that reduction, or even better `numbers.reduce((acc, num) => acc + (num == 4), 0)`

Comment: @Bergi `(acc) => ++acc` works too, which solves the typo that the OP had

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! the side of the ++ mattered. Thought that it didn't count in this case for some reason.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes, that would work as well, but one should not mutate the accumulator in a  `reduce` call. `1+acc` or `acc+1` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Phil for finding the appropriate canonical faster than I could

Comment: @Bergi why shouldn't you "mutate the accumulator in a `reduce` call"? The only time the value actually changes is the return of the callback each time, so it doesn't corrupt any data or anything.

Comment: @Samathingamajig a) as you say it's unnecessary, so you shouldn't do it b) when using `reduce` one wants to follow the functional programming paradigm, which favours immutability.

Comment: @Bergi im just getting started with js, but respect for the neat code optimization. Thank you